# Is the Maxwell stress tensor covariant or contravariant?

Tags: electromagnetism, metric-tensor, conventions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

So I am currently taking a course in Electrodynamics, and I was having a look at the Wikipedia article for the [Electromagnetic Stress Energy Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) (EMSET). I saw that the [Maxwell stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_stress_tensor) (MST) is simply the spacial part of the EMSET.

It appears that the EMSET tensor is of $(2,0)$ shape,
$$T^{ij}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\left(F^{ik}F^j{}_{k}-\frac{1}{4}\eta^{ij}F_{kl}F^{kl}\right)$$
Here $\mathbf{F}$ is the [Electromagnetic stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor), which is most certainly contravariant, so I think it is safe to say that $\mathbf{T}$ is as well.

But, Wiki have defined the MST *covariantly*,
$$\sigma_{ij}=\varepsilon_0E_iE_j+\frac{1}{\mu_0}B_iB_j-\frac{g_{ij}}{2}\left(\varepsilon_0|\boldsymbol E|^2+\frac{1}{\mu_0}|\boldsymbol B|^2\right).$$
And they seem to claim
$$T^{ij}=-\sigma_{ij}\\ \text{when}~~i,j\neq 0.$$
But equating a covariant tensor to a contravariant one seems wrong to me. Is it instead supposed to be
$$T^{ij}=-\sigma^{ij}\\ \text{when}~~i,j\neq 0$$
Where
$$\sigma^{ij}=\varepsilon_0E^iE^j+\frac{1}{\mu_0}B^iB^j-\frac{g^{ij}}{2}\left(\varepsilon_0|\boldsymbol E|^2+\frac{1}{\mu_0}|\boldsymbol B|^2\right)~?$$

What's more interesting is that the Cauchy stress tensor in fluid mechanics is typically defined covariantly, see [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301921/).

So yeah... basically I'm asking if the convention is to define the MST covariantly or contravariantly. The distinction really matters to me.

Comment: In the (+---) metric $E^i = - E_i$ etc. so it is better to use the Minkowski metric to lower all Greek indices, then move to Cartesian components. Use $\alpha$ for 0,1,2,3 and $i,j$ for 1,2,3.

Comment: Well, since we have a metric tensor, we can always raise and lower indices, so it is really just a matter of convention.

Comment: @K.defaoite By nature of geometry, the Faraday tensor is double-covariant. The stress-energy tensor is double covariant (think of its definition from GR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Hilbert_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), but in the presence of a metric tensor, you can do whatever you want with the components.

Comment: @DanielC Right, but in general $\sigma_{ij}\neq \sigma^{ij}$. So is it 
$$T^{ij}=-\sigma_{ij}\\ \text{when}~~i,j\neq 0$$
Or is it 
$$T^{ij}=-\sigma^{ij}\\ \text{when}~~i,j\neq 0$$

Comment: $\sigma_{ij}$ uses Cartesian components of the 3D electric and magnetic fields, therefore it only makes sense to consider $T_{ij}$ from $T_{\mu\nu}$.